# using blob or base64 which is more efficient for uploading

Tags: javascript, cropit

we are using **cropit** for cropping image at client side then uploading base64 string to server , 
but some time for large images it crashes mobile browsers with low ram , 
is it good idea to convert base64 to blob [[Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript]) then upload that on server or it will effect more mobile users as first image will be covered to based64 for cropping and then back to blob .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base64 encoding takes up [about a third more space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#Encoded_size_increase) than the original data. It was designed to safely send data through text (e.g. in mail bodies).

You're better off using the binary image, as it will be smaller and so quicker to upload.

Go with [BLOB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), mate.